# QGIS raster to vector with shapefile feed procedure

Tags: qgis, polygonize

Does a procedure like Polygonize raster to vector exist in QGIS that can do the following:

I have a raster image, a shapefile (.shp) with all the regions of interest and I need a vector output with those polygons only.

Comment: In QGIS from the menubar: `Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)`, this allows you to both polygonize and **clip** your raster to a region of interest using your shapefile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Joseph, do you mean the mask option?It does not allow me to enter a shapefile there .shp.  As a matter of fact i just saw behind the window there is a message "TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable". maybe you know something about this error? Does it take a shapefile if the error did not exist?

Comment: @ODstuck - Apologies, the term **mask** is also used for vectors for other tools (annoying!). In which case, you could use the **Clipper** tool and then the **Polygonize** tool.

Comment: I believe that Clipper tool outputs a raster again? It has a mask option yes, and this inputs shapefiles, but still, how does this assist then the Polygonize tool?

Comment: You use the **Clipper** tool with the shapefile as the mask to output a raster showing your region of interest. You then use this output as the input to the **Polygonize** tool (no need to use a mask). This will produce a vector output of your clipped raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joseph correctly stated, the closest to my need is as he suggests:

You use the Clipper tool with the shapefile as the mask to output a raster showing your region of interest. You then use this output as the input to the Polygonize tool (no need to use a mask). This will produce a vector output of your clipped raster.