# QGIS creating a layer to draw over Google Streets Map

Tags: qgis, google-maps

Is there a way to create a layer that covers Google Maps blocks

for example this is the google map,

[image]

and this is the layer that i want to create
[image]

since i cant use  snap on google maps im trying to work around it and find a way to automatically create those blocks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QGIS raster to vector with shapefile feed procedure](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220541/qgis-raster-to-vector-with-shapefile-feed-procedure)

Comment: @MartinHügi Google maps layer is a Tile Layer so I think that solution won't work here

Comment: You could export the current Google canvas content to tif, and re-add that as a new layer to QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your efforts but i managed to get the result i want this way:

- Vector -> OpenLayersMap -> DownloadData (this will download the google maps that has been loaded in your current screen)
- add your OSM layer and choose Lines
- save the Lines layer as a SHP file
- select all lines and from Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Single parts to multi part
- Create a fixed distance buffer to the newly added multipart - this is a bit tricky since i have experienced some differences in measurements - but i chose 0.0005 to be the distance
- convert the buffer to Polygon to Lines
- and then change to Polygons to lines into Lines to polygons

this last step will change everything into polygons so just choose the streets and delete its polygon and now you'll have each of the google maps blocks as a separate block in it's own layer which can be edited

if its unclear just write it down and ill try to explain

Answer (score 3):

I think the best thing to do is to switch to OpenStreetMap and download the vector data you need then do your processing.

if the area you need is small you can directly download it using QGIS : Vector -> OpenStreetMap -> Download OSM Data , or if it's too big you can either download it from one of the repositories ( like Geofabrik ) or use overpass API provided by OpenStreetMap

Answer (score 2):

I would either suggest downloading OpenStreetMap data either online as extracts for larger files (Geofabrik, Metro Extracts or HOT OpenStreetMap for a unique area) or within QGIS for smaller files (Vector - OpenStreetMap - Download OSM Data).

This will provide you with vector data that you could edit yourself or use as a basemap to trace over the specific area you want to show. Creating a shapefile and then manually digitising the Google Maps blocks for the site in question.

For either this will allow you to style the resulting vectors in a similar blue/turquoise overlay that is shown in the image above. Some tinkering would be needed to get it looking just as you want but this shouldn't be too difficult.

*edit - previous answer didn't show hence similarity, mine offers some clarity in further digitising that could be done so will not delete.*

Comment: You have the same answer as @Hicham Zourahi